# UEFI, Dual boot with encryption

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I have gone through all of the basic information about efi and dual boot. I have windows already installed, an efi boot partition from that windows installation and an encrypted partition to install ubuntu on. Yes, I am booting the install media in uefi mode as well.

After select my encrypted partition as '/' and the windows uefi partition is already selected as "efi system partition" by the installer. I press install.Then I get an error:

```
the grub-efi-amd64-signed package failed to install into /target/
```

My syslog references:

```
grub-install: error: attempt to install to encrypted disk without cryptodisk enabled. Set `GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK=y' in file `/etc/default/grub'.
Failed: grub-install --target=x86_64-efi
```

I can make the change to the grub file but when I go to update-grub I get another error

```
/usr/sbin/grub-probe:error:failed to get canonical path of /cow.
```